# duda de un ejercicio de arrays con JS

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, ordenamiento

```html
input: array = [1,2,4,5,6,8,2,5,3,2,1]

output: array = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,1], [4,1], [5,2], [6,1], [8,1] ]

seria ordenar array 1 ascendentemente y agregar el numero de veces que se repite en el array
```

input: array = [1,2,4,5,6,8,2,5,3,2,1]

output: array = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,1], [4,1], [5,2], [6,1], [8,1] ]

seria ordenar array 1 ascendentemente y agregar el numero de veces que se repite en el array

Comment: *el número de veces que se repite en el array*, que es lo que buscas encontrar que se repita?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Aparte del enunciado de tu tarea, has intentado hacer algo por ti mismo? Deberías subir el código de lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte. No le hacemos las tareas a nadie por aqui. Saludos

Comment: ¿Exactamente cuál es tu duda? Por favor, dinos qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Para próximas ocasiones, por favor, publica cuál tu duda en concreto y lo que ya has intentado, así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es ordenar tu array por valores ascendentes únicos y, luego contar el número de veces que existe ese valor en el array.

Te voy a explicar primero las tres operaciones básicas que tienes que hacer y luego las mostraré funcionando en conjunto.

En primer lugar, podemos obtener todos los valores únicos utilizando Set y descomponiéndolo en un Array.

```
const myUniqueValuesArray = [...new Set(myArray)];
```

Después de eso podemos ordenar los valores de menor a mayor con el método `.sort()` del prototipo `Array`.

```
const mySortedArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => a > b);
```

Por último, para obtener el número de veces que aparece un elemento en un array, lo mejor es usar el método `.filter()` y comprobar el `.length` del resultado.

```
const timesNAppearsInArray = myArray.filter(val => val === n).length;
```

Sabiendo esto, te dejo cómo quedaría lo que parece que quieres hacer.

```js
const myArray = [
  1,
  2,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  8,
  2,
  5,
  3,
  2,
  1
];

const uniqueValsArr = [...new Set(myArray)]; // Separamos el Array en valores únicos

const sortedArray = uniqueValsArr.sort((x, y) => x > y); // Los ordenamos de menor a mayor

const appearancesArray = sortedArray.map(value => [value, myArray.filter(myArrValue => value === myArrValue).length]); // Iteramos sobre nuestro array ordenado y devolvemos un array incluyendo el número de veces que aparece cada valor del array ordenado en el array original

console.log(appearancesArray);


// Y todo junto quedaría...
const uniqueApprearancesArray = [...new Set(myArray)]
  .sort((x, y) => x > y)
  .map(val => [val, myArray.filter(myArrVal => myArrVal === val).length]);

console.log(uniqueApprearancesArray)
```